# Android studio ImageButton change from one image to another

Tags: java, android

I was having some problems with the `ImageButton`. I have put 3 images in the drawable folder. The images are named *e1*, *e2* and *e3*.

I have made it so that when you click a button the button image changes from *e1* to *e2*. Can I make it so that the button changes to *e3* if its already on *e2*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int count = 0;
    e1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {             
                   public void onClick(View v)  {               
                                 if(count == 0)
                                    {
                                //Set Image 2
                                  count++;
                                   } 
                        else if(count == 1)
                         {
                             // set Image 3
                         }

                   }  
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to handle this manually in the button click event.

Set the current drawble id for example in the button tag (button.setTag), and check the tag value on click (getTag()) to change it to another value.